# Show/Hide the part of the form based on checkbox selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two checkboxes `First` and `Second`

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" /> First

    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" /> Second
```

And `form` with three input content, `name`,`phone`,`address`.

```
    <form id="f1">
    <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="first">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

When the `first` checkbox is selected - display the `first two content` - `name` and `phone`, Similarly for the `second` checkbox if selected - display the `last content` - `address`

What I have tried:

https://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm1102/16hgpt0z/3/

I tried to hide the whole form:

```
    var form1 = document.querySelector("#f1"),
        form2 = document.querySelector("#f2"),
        check1 = document.querySelector("#checkbox1"),
        check2 = document.querySelector("#checkbox2");

    check1.onchange = function() {
    form1.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
```

`css`

```
    .hidden {
    display: none;
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to show only first two content or last content depending on the checkbox selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added two options first in vanila js and second one is in jquery

```
    /*---- Plain JS----*/
    check1.onchange = function() {
        if(this.checked){
        document.querySelector("#address").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
      }
      else{
        document.querySelector("#address").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
      }
    }

    check2.onchange = function() {
        if(this.checked){
        document.querySelector("#name").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("#phone").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
      }
      else{
        document.querySelector("#name").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
        document.querySelector("#phone").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
      }
    }

/*----Jquery----*/
    $(document).on('change','#checkbox1',function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('#address').closest('.form-group').hide();
      }
      else{
        $('#address').closest('.form-group').show();
      }
    });

    $(document).on('change','#checkbox2',function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('#name').closest('.form-group').hide();
        $('#phone').closest('.form-group').hide();
      }
      else{
        $('#name').closest('.form-group').show();
        $('#phone').closest('.form-group').show();
      }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1zu0nsjr/

Answer (score 0):

I used JQuery for something similar sometime back.

```js
function firstCheckBox() {
  $("#address1").hide();
   $("#name1").show();
  $("#phone1").show();

}

function secondCheckBox() {
  $("#name1").hide();
  $("#phone1").hide();
  $("#address1").show();


}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" onclick="firstCheckBox()" /> First

<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" onclick="secondCheckBox()" /> Second


<form id="f1">
  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="name1">
      <label for="first">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="phone1">
      <label for="">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="address1">
      <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can use `input type = radio` and have the same name for both of you want only 1 to be checked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## You need a radio button for this functionality

Radio buttons can only have one option picked at a time, that seems to be what you want you are not going to get the functionality you require with a checkbox, which by it's own design can have multiple options checked at the same time.

### So for your HTML you can do the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-01/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
      <label for="male">Male</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
      <label for="female">Female</label><br>


    <form id="f1">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="first">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" required>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
</html>
```

#### for your JS you can do the following.

```
$('#male').click(function() {
  $("#name").show();
  $("#phone").show();
  $("#address").hide();
});

$('#female').click(function() {
  $("#name").hide().
  $("#phone").hide().
  $("#address").show();
});
```